# How to debug Error(no valid constructor)?

Tags: java, serialization, serializable

There isn't error until I use writeobject but it keeps give me no valid constructor error, even if I created no-arg constructor and UID, what was the problem in my coding?

Here's an error code in console

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: AirSwift.Game_player$Player; no valid constructor
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at AirSwift.Game_stage.GameLoad(Game_stage.java:168)
at AirSwift.Game_main$7.actionPerformed(Game_main.java:168)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here's a class implements Externalizable

```
public class Player implements Externalizable { 
    /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public int x, y, mode, attackspeed, speed, speedinattack, firecount, hp, mp, time;
        public boolean modechanging = false;                       
        public int modechangecount = 0;                            
        Image Player_img = new ImageIcon("Images/Player/Player_0.png").getImage();
        Image []Player_Mode_img;
        String sound_fire, sound_change;

        public Player(){

        }

        public Player(int hp){
            this.ChangeMode(1);
            this.hp = hp;
            this.mp = 100;
            this.x = 100;
            this.y = 600;
            this.time = 0;
        }
        Image AnimeMode(){                                                                                
            switch(mode){
            case 1: 
                if(modechangecount < 10) return Player_Mode_img[0];
                else if((9<modechangecount)&&(modechangecount<20)) return Player_Mode_img[1];
                else return Player_Mode_img[2];
            case 2:
                return Player_Mode_img[0];
            case 3:
                if(modechangecount < 10) return Player_Mode_img[0];
                else if((9<modechangecount)&&(modechangecount<20)) return Player_Mode_img[1];
                else return Player_Mode_img[2];
            default: return default_img;
            }
        }

        public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            this.x = in.readInt(); this.y = in.readInt(); this.hp = in.readInt(); this.time = in.readInt();
        }

        public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            out.writeInt(this.x); out.writeInt(this.y); out.writeInt(this.hp); out.writeInt(this.time); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add default constructor to `AirSwift.Game_player` as well or declare `Player` as `public static`